# UDK error, how to examine crash dump

Tags: windbg, crash-dumps

I am working on a game in UDK, and sometimes the game crashes when restarting the level or trying to open a new one.

I cannot find the problem trough the log files, they are just displaying a critical error.

Now I am trying to fix it by examining the crash dump, but I do not have a clue how to do this. Does anyone have an idea how I can further investigate the problem? I tried some things that I found online and this is what I have so far.

```
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for UDK.exe - 
eax=00000000 ebx=39280070 ecx=0cdc0f10 edx=ffffffff esi=2a193f40 edi=296f96a0
eip=01c2caf3 esp=007cdf84 ebp=2c0132b0 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010246
UDK!GetStackOwnerClass+0x10a73:
01c2caf3 8b10            mov     edx,dword ptr [eax]  ds:002b:00000000=????????
0:000> !sym noisy
noisy mode - symbol prompts on
0:000> lmvm ntdll
start    end        module name
77890000 77a10000   ntdll      (export symbols)       ntdll.dll
    Loaded symbol image file: ntdll.dll
    Mapped memory image file: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
    Image path: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
    Image name: ntdll.dll
    Timestamp:        Thu Aug 29 03:50:31 2013 (521EA8E7)
    CheckSum:         00140982
    ImageSize:        00180000
    File version:     6.1.7601.18247
    Product version:  6.1.7601.18247
    File flags:       0 (Mask 3F)
    File OS:          40004 NT Win32
    File type:        2.0 Dll
    File date:        00000000.00000000
    Translations:     0409.04b0
    CompanyName:      Microsoft Corporation
    ProductName:      Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
    InternalName:     ntdll.dll
    OriginalFilename: ntdll.dll
    ProductVersion:   6.1.7601.18247
    FileVersion:      6.1.7601.18247 (win7sp1_gdr.130828-1532)
    FileDescription:  NT Layer DLL
    LegalCopyright:   © Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most basic analysis in WInDbg is done with

```
.symfix
.reload
!analyze -v
```

Since it crashes, there should be an exception somewhere. Try

```
.ecxr
.exr -1
```

Also the call stack is potentially interesting. Since this is about UDK (Unreal Engine Development Kit), I assume it's written in C++ and thus we need a native call stack

```
k
```